# how to gather delete all() query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
        for item in items:
            item.children.all().delete()
```

how do I combine this into one delete query? where children are prefetch_related.

```
items.values_list("children", flat=True).all().delete()
```

which doesn't work i think it deleted items instead of children

Comment: Can you share the relevant models? What is `deleted_by_id`.

Comment: it;s just a field so delete doesn't delete the row, but instead just update the field `deleted_by_id`

Answer (score 0):

Work from the `Child` model:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__in=items).delete()
```

this will normally make *two* queries: one to filter the `Child`ren and retrieve these, and one to delete the corresponding records. If there are `ForeignKey`s that point *to* the `Child` model, it can produce additional queries, since Django manually runs the `on_delete=…` handlers.

These two queries is a minimum, and using the code where you enumerate over the `items` would only produce two queries *per* `item`, hence the above is definitely more efficient.